# delphi substring count performance

Tags: string, performance, delphi, substring, delphi-xe2

I have some functions to count a substring in a string delimited by spaces:

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses System.SysUtils,windows;

//s=string to search in
//t=string to search for
//cs=delimiters

function f0(const s,t:string;const cs:tsyscharset):integer;
var
  p,q:pchar;
  u:string;
begin
  result:=0;
  p:=pointer(s);
  if p<>nil then
    while p^<>#0 do
    begin
      while (p^<>#0) and charinset(p^,cs) do inc(p);
      q:=p;
      while (p^<>#0) and not charinset(p^,cs) do inc(p);
      if p>q then
      begin
        setstring(u,q,p-q);
        //writeln('[',u,']');
        if u=t then inc(result);
      end;
    end;
end;

function f1(const s,t:string;const cs:tsyscharset):integer;
var
  i,j,l:integer;
  u:string;
begin
  result:=0;
  l:=length(s);
  i:=1;
  while i<=l do
  begin
    while (i<=l) and charinset(s[i],cs) do inc(i);
    j:=i;
    while (i<=l) and not charinset(s[i],cs) do inc(i);
    if i>j then
    begin
      u:=copy(s,j,i-j);
      //writeln('[',u,']');
      if u=t then inc(result);
    end;
  end;
end;

function f2(const s,t:string;const cs:tsyscharset):integer;
var
  i,j,l:integer;
  u:string;
begin
  result:=0;
  l:=length(s);
  i:=1;
  while i<=l do
  begin
    while (i<=l) and charinset(s[i],cs) do inc(i);
    j:=i;
    while (i<=l) and not charinset(s[i],cs) do inc(i);
    if i>j then
    begin
      setlength(u,i-j);
      move(s[j],pointer(u)^,(i-j)*2);
      //writeln('[',u,']');
      if u=t then inc(result);
    end;
  end;
end;

type
  tfunc=function(const s,t:string;const cs:tsyscharset):integer;

const
  s='  de foo   de'+#13+' baz blah de  de blah'+#10+' asd de qwe rtz   un f'+#9+' t de ds w de  ';
  t='de';
  cs=[' ',#13,#10,#9];//CR,LF,TAB
  n=5000000;

procedure time(i:integer;f:tfunc);
var
  j,k:integer;
  start,finish,freq:int64;
begin
  QueryPerformanceCounter(start);
  for j := 1 to n do k:=f(s,t,cs);
  QueryPerformanceCounter(finish);
  QueryPerformanceFrequency(freq);
  Writeln(Format('f%u:%u:%.3fs',[i,k,(finish-start)/freq]));
end;

const
  funcs:array[0..2] of tfunc=(f0,f1,f2);
var
  i:integer;
begin
  setpriorityclass(GetCurrentProcess(), REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);
  for i := low(funcs) to high(funcs) do time(i,funcs[i]);
  readln
end.
```

The speed results are

```
f0:7:7,624s
f1:7:8,066s
f2:7:6,454s
```

My first question is: Why is f2 faster than f0?

My second question is: Do you have an idea how I can optimize this even more (without inline assembler)?

IDE: Delphi XE2 (Unicode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why is it faster? Impossible to guess without a profiler. And it will depend on the CPU you run on.

I guess the faster will be processed by `f2` since `SetLength()` will avoid reallocation most of the time, whereas `SetString()` will always release the memory before allocating it. It depends on your case.

For even faster process, with the same algorithm (you may find something even more optimized), I'd try:

```
const
  cs = [32,13,10,9];  

function f2(const s,t:string):integer;
var
  i,j,l:integer;
begin
  result := 0;
  l := length(s);
  i := 1;
  while i<=l do
  begin
    while (i<=l) and (ord(s[i]) in cs) do inc(i);
    j:=i;
    while (i<=l) and not(ord(s[i]) in cs) do inc(i);
    if (i>j) and CompareMem(pointer(s[j]),pointer(t),(i-j)*sizeof(char)) then
      inc(result);
  end;
end;
```

That is:

- The CharInSet is not worth it for control chars;
- Using a static set is IMHO faster than passing a parameter (but you can use a parameter if you want);
- Do not use a temporary variable (this is the slow part of your algorithm, I think), but a good old `CompareMem` - there is still room for improvement here.

You may try writing:

```
const 
  cs: set of 0..32 = [32,13,10,9];
```

Which may be a bit faster, since the generated ASM code will be a fast bit-looking instruction, whereas the first version will use a list of comparison. But I think this won't make a big difference.

In all cases, I guess that you should better:

- Not optimize too early - use first a profiler to guess what is slow and worth rewriting;
- Optimize with *real data*, not a simplified fixed set as in your benchmark: you would optimized for one kind of data, whereas it won't be necessary true with real data.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your function, but it seems that it runs in an endless loop. If I add the keyword not to the second (ord(s[i]) in cs) it crashes.

Comment: Now I got it. It is many times faster than my functions, even with cs parameter.
Thanks!